# Limit of a rational function as x approaches infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

If I have this

$$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{3x}{6x}.$$
it is equivalent to this:

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{3}{6} = \frac{1}{2} $$

But couldn't I write the first expression as
$$ \frac{\lim_{x\to\infty}3x}{\lim_{x\to\infty}6x} = \frac{3(\infty)}{6(\infty)}$$

From my understanding that just becomes $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ meaning there is no limit.

I'm clearly missing something here so to why these two don't converge to the same answer.
Can anyone help?

Comment: "But couldn't I write the first expression as" No. The limit of the numerator and the denominator must exist as real numbers ( with the denominator not zero) in order to apply the quotient rule of limits. The lesson is that do not blindly apply limit laws without checking the assumptions.

Comment: @user1046533 Please post your comment as an answer.

Comment: Can anyone tell me why the question is being marked down. Surely it's not for misunderstanding something?

Comment: Where did the "-" in  $-\infty$ come from?

Comment: Thanks @StevenAlexisGregory , that was a mistake, fixed now.

Comment: @EthanBolker: Done. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If “plugging in” the limit point (including ∞) gives you an [indeterminate form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form), it does **not** mean “there is no limit”.  It means that you need to use another method for evaluating the limit.

With this particular example, you can just cancel the $x$'s.

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{3x}{6x} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{3}{6} = \frac{1}{2}$$

In more complicated cases, use [L'Hôspital's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule).

Comment: Thanks @Dan , I will do some more investigation around what you're saying.

Answer (score 1):

Already in the first [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4467139/limit-of-a-rational-function-as-x-approaches-infinity#comment9361427_4467139):

> "But couldn't I write the first expression as"

No. The limit of the numerator and the denominator must exist as real numbers (with the denominator not zero) in order to apply the quotient rule of limits.

The lesson is that do not blindly apply limit laws without checking the assumptions.